# Golang excel file reading

Tags: excel, go, reader

I'm using tealeg xlsx library to read an excel file https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx . They have documentation here https://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/ . It works perfectly fine if I call the `OpenFile()` by local directory, but I wanted to use an `http.Request.FormFile()` return object which is of type `multipart.Form`.  How do I use this file to be read by the tealeg package?

Tealeg's `OpenReaderAt()` looks like something I should use, but the multipart. Form object returned from `http.Request.FormFile()` returns a file interface but I'm not sure how to access the readerAt object? https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`func OpenReaderAt(r io.ReaderAt, size int64) (*File, error)`

`xlsx.OpenReaderAt` takes in an `io.ReaderAt` interface and `multipart.File` also implements `io.ReaderAt`.

So you can directly pass it to `xlsx.OpenReaderAt`

```
var (
file multipart.File
size int64
err error
)

file, _,err = req.FormFile("key")
// size = // Calculate size
xlsx.OpenReaderAt(file,size)
```

Comment: How do I know that File is of io.ReaderAt interface? ReaderAt interface requires implementation of "ReadAt()" function https://godoc.org/io#ReaderAt . However... File (returned from req.FormFIle) does not seem to implement any functions: https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File

Comment: `multipart.File` is an interface that embeds other interfaces, one of which is `io.ReaderAt`. You can see that in the [link](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#File) you posted.

Comment: @user3125693 Is there anything else to clear up in the answer ?

Comment: Nope you answered it perfectly. I didn't actually know you could embed an interface into another interface. Thank you!